# itext7 how to have AGPL licence?

Tags: itext7

I would like help to use html2pdf. I have a trial license, this license is now expired. I have disclosed my code source to Github. And would like to know, how continue to use html2pdf with AGPL

Someone need to send me a new license?
Need to declare my Github project, somewhere?

> com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKeyException License expired.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for iText7](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: I agree (and I am an iText employee).

Comment: Another iText employee here who agrees.

Comment: i have updated my source code with

     CounterFactory.getInstance().setCounter(new AGPLWarningRemoverCounter ());


     public static class AGPLWarningRemoverCounter extends DefaultCounter {
     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private static void plusOne() {
         return;
     }
 }


all source code , an eclipse project

https://github.com/bennnnnnn/iTextConvertHtml/blob/master/src/htmlFileToPDF/Convert.java

but i have this error :  

    Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.licensekey.LicenseKeyException: Signature was corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here.

1. You have shared exactly one method of your entire codebase.
   https://github.com/bennnnnnn/iTextConvertHtml

This does not fulfill the definition of "open sourcing your project" as dictated by the AGPL license.

2. You have not included a license file (hard requirement for AGPL compliance)

As such, you do not currently fulfill the terms of the AGPL license.

There are two options:

- pay for a license
- open source your project entirely

We have  released a blogpost on how to open source your project to be AGPL compliant. You can certainly check that out for inspiration.

https://itextpdf.com/blog/how-do-i-make-sure-my-software-complies-agpl-how-can-i-use-itext-free

Comment: thx for your answer. i have updated my project with all eclipse source code

Comment: did this project ever get AGPL license?